# Azure database not available

Tags: azure-sql-database

I am getting the error message

> Database not available

from **Azure** after the version got updated to V12.

In **Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio**, I am getting the error

> The database is not accessible

but I am still able to run queries despite the prompt.

Is there anyway to solve this issues?

[image: Database not available]

Comment: can you provide server / database name to snarlap at microsoft dot com. Thanks!

Comment: I have the same stange error - it happens when I try to connect an app to a SQL Azure DB which is using EF database seeding - I have no idea what the specific error message - will have to dig about in the logs